# How to set a recurring holiday on the same date every year (disregarding the year component) with java using java.util.Calendar?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, gregorian-calendar, java.util.calendar

I am making a calendar that allows you to add a specific holiday which recurs each year automatically.
My WorkdayCalendar.class needs 2 methods:
-setHoliday(Calendar date) which sets a holiday only within that year
-setRecurringHoliday(Calendar date) which should (preferably) use setHoliday() and set it recurring each year. 
How do I implement the logic that checks if it is a new year? I am adding holidays to a HashSet named holidaysList. I need a method that checks if it is a new year and then adds a specified holiday.
The setHoliday works fine and has been tested wih unitTests.

```
public void setHoliday(Calendar date) {
    this.date = date.getTime();
    if (!isHoliday(date)) {
        holidaysList.add(this.date);
    }
}

public void setRecurringHoliday(Calendar date) {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm");
    GregorianCalendar todaysDate = new GregorianCalendar();

    System.out.println(
            sdf.format("Todays date: " + todaysDate.getTime()) + "\n");

    int thisYear = todaysDate.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int chosenYear = date.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    System.out.println("Chosen year: " + chosenYear + "\nThis year: " + thisYear);

    date.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);
    int nextYear = date.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    System.out.println("Next year: " + nextYear);


    /*What to do here???*/
    if (thisYear == nextYear){
        setHoliday(date);
        System.out.println("recurring holiday added");
    }

}

private boolean isHoliday(Calendar date) {
    this.date = date.getTime();
    return isWeekend(date) || holidaysList.contains(this.date);
}

private boolean isWeekend(Calendar date) {
     int chosenDay = date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    return chosenDay == Calendar.SATURDAY || chosenDay == Calendar.SUNDAY;
}
```

Comment: I  would add two lists: one for holiday within year (you have it as holidaysList) and second as recurringHolidayList. Inside isHoliday() I would add another or condition isRecurringHoliday(date). isRecurringHoliday() would go through all elements of  recurringHolidayList and compare if date.getDay().equals(element.getDay()) and date.getMonth().equals(element.getMonth()). 

Correct me if I missunderstood something.

Comment: @t4u That would be a good start and thank you, but this only checks if the recurring holiday exists in a seperated List doesnt it? What i need is further implementation of the logic inside setRecurringHoliday. How do I implement "if it's a new year, set all Holidays stored in recurringHolidayList for this year"?

Comment: Nevermind your tip helped! I posted a solution below. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using terrible date-time classes that were years ago supplanted by the *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

## `MonthDay`

For a month and day-of-month without year, use `MonthDay`.

```
MonthDay xmas = MonthDay.of( Month.DECEMBER , 25 ) ;
```

Your set of holidays should be a set `MonthDay` objects, from what I can discern of your Question. I find your overall Question confusing as its logic falls short of what you need for the usual workplace holiday tracking.

```
Set< MonthDay > holidays = new TreeSet<>() ;
holidays.add( xmas ) ;
```

For a date, use `LocalDate`.

Apply a year to get a date.

```
LocalDate xmas2020 = xmas.atYear( 2020 ) ;
```

To get current year, use `Year`, and specify a time zone. For any given moment, the date, and therefore possibly the year, varies around the globe by zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
Year currentYear = Year.now( z ) ;
LocalDate xmasThisYear = currentYear.atMonthDay( xmas ) ;
```

Add to `Year` for next year.

```
Year nextYear = currentYear.plusYears( 1 ) ;
LocalDate xmasNextYear = nextYear.atMonthDay( xmas ) ;
```

Ask if a date is this year or next.

```
boolean isThisYear = Year.from( localDate ).equals( currentYear ) ;
boolean isNextYear = Year.from( localDate ).equals( nextYear ) ;
boolean isFutureYear = Year.from( localDate ).isAfter( currentYear ) ;
```

For your check of the weekend, define an `EnumSet` of the desired day of week values as defined in the `DayOfWeek` enum.

```
Set< DayOfWeek > weekend = EnumSet.of( DayOfWeek.SATURDAY , DayOfWeek.SUNDAY ) ;
boolean isWeekend = weekend.contains( localDate.getDayOfWeek() ) ;
```

Comment: The reason I am using these old classes is because the task given to me describes the solution with these classes, but I am not sure if I HAVE to use them and problem is that I am not allowed to ask them either..And thank you for correcting that. I will see if I can solve this using these steps.